# Конфигурирование nginx в docker для нескольких доменов

Tags: nginx, docker

У меня проблема с конфигурированием nginx в контейнерах docker.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    build:
      ./nginx
    ports:
        - 80:80
        - 443:443
    links:
        - php
  php:
    build:
      ./php
    volumes:
      - ../domains:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - 82:80
    depends_on:
      - db
  ...
```

dockerfile для nginx:

```
FROM nginx
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 1;
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name local.test1.ru;
        root ../domains/test1.ru/;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://php/test1.ru/;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
    }
}
```

когда захожу по пути: `local.test1.ru/wp-admin`, то он редиректит меня на `local.test1.ru/test1.ru/wp-admin`, хотя должен остаться на старом.
в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: root - укажите абсолютный путь

Comment: почему бы не использовать  сразу php:7-apache или php:7-fpm?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно выключить редирект для proxy

```
proxy_redirect off;

# бонус, на что обратить внимание:
# proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
# proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
# proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
# proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
# proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
# proxy_connect_timeout 60;
# proxy_send_timeout 60;
# proxy_read_timeout 60;
```

пример

```
location / {
   # ... 
   proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
   proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_redirect     off;
   proxy_pass http://php/test1.ru/;
   # ...
}
```

Так как конфигурация попадает в образ на этапе сборки, то нужно пересобрать образ, например так - `docker-compose up --build`. Можно монтировать директорию с конфигурацией nginx, чтобы не пере-собирать образ каждый раз при изменении.

Comment: указал абсолютный путь root, выключил редирект для proxy - ничего не поменялось. в переменную $REQUEST_URL все равно попадает путь /test1.ru/ для запроса local.test1.ru/, хотя должен быть /

Comment: нужно "пересобрать" образ --build / docker-compose up --build